# Using setcap [capabilities] in cross-compiled platform

Tags: cross-compiling, linux-capabilities

I am looking for sandboxing applications in cross-compiled environment. I need to setcap [set capabilities] on a process. However, that directory is read-only.

I am using makefiles to create the cross compiled image and not a yocto build system

Can someone please suggest how can this be achieved?

To achieve this, am trying to setcap to a process on the host before the image is created. However, when I check with getcap in target, the capabilities are not set.

Comment: You can't copy capabilities from one system to another without something on that target system re-granting them. Package systems like deb and rpm have installation scripts and native support to add these bits to files, but those installation systems are typically run via sudo or as root.